# How to use a sub-domain for a specific content type?

Tags: 8, domain-access, subsites

I have a blog content type. My client would like the domain to be blog.example.com for only that content type. I would like to know the best way to approach this, whether it be a rewrite rule or using [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) Module.

I have installed the [Domain Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/domain) module, and created my primary domain (example.com) and another domain (blog.example.com) for the blog - but am now not sure how to go about assigning that domain for my blog content type.

Any advice is much appreciated - please keep in mind this is for Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

In [hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Entity%21entity.api.php/function/hook_ENTITY_TYPE_view_alter/8.2.x) you can check for your content type and redirect here.
Lets give a try , maybe it will help